# Read from database while having two types of users

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am working on some android app where two types of user can login and database will display their info. Lets say one type of user will be customer ("Users") and other will be restaurant ("Restaurants"). Problem starts when I am trying to read user details from database. App works fine and display user info when I have just one type of user (child "Users"), but when I add another one (child "Restaurants"),  it seems that app is doesn't know from which child user is logged in? Hopefully it makes sense :)

//JSON

```
{
  "Restaurants" : {
    "4kASMGuVlxgk8HiDsxEt7IcSo4y2" : {
      "restaurantEmail" : "res1@gmail.com",
      "restaurantName" : "res1",
      "restaurantPhone" : "123456"
    },
    "6FwZR8rYxyVKm8FC8v0jV4ZwgVs2" : {
      "restaurantEmail" : "1604@gmail.com",
      "restaurantName" : "restaurant1604",
      "restaurantPhone" : "123456"
    },
    "vERcsGqBA0VNDjXfNvrseA29UGc2" : {
      "restaurantEmail" : "restaurant3@gmail.com",
      "restaurantName" : "restaurant3",
      "restaurantPhone" : "123456"
    }
  },
  "Users" : {
    "3BCqSyocaScBiviSUf2QAXo5Fdu1" : {
      "phoneNumber" : "123456",
      "userEmail" : "test3@gmail.com",
      "userName" : "test3"
    },
    "wzz9NBQt2YfFikMHTaMIcdRyCRI2" : {
      "phoneNumber" : "123456",
      "userEmail" : "test5@gmail.com",
      "userName" : "test5"
    }
  }
}
```

//JAVA

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    WelcomeActivity = new Intent(this,com.example.danie.dine.Activities.WelcomeActivity.class);
    BookingManagementActivity = new Intent(this,com.example.danie.dine.Activities.BookingManagementActivity.class);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    userID = currentUser.getUid();
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mRef = mDatabase.getReference("Users");

    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                // User is signed in

                showMessage("Successfully signed in with: " + user.getEmail());
            } else {
                // User is signed out
                showMessage("Successfully signed out.");
            }
            // ...
        }
    };
```

//adding missing part of code

```
mRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            showInfo(dataSnapshot);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

// JAVA to trying to read from DB - not working

```
private void showInfo(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
        UserInformation uInfo = new UserInformation();
        uInfo.setUserName(ds.child(userID).getValue(UserInformation.class).getUserName()); //get username
        uInfo.setUserEmail(ds.child(userID).getValue(UserInformation.class).getUserEmail()); //get user email
        uInfo.setPhoneNumber(ds.child(userID).getValue(UserInformation.class).getPhoneNumber()); //get user phone number
        //display user details
        lblUserName.setText(uInfo.getUserName()); //error points here
        lblUserEmail.setText(uInfo.getUserEmail());
        lblUserPhone.setText(uInfo.getPhoneNumber());
    }
}
```

//missing part of code #2

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mAuthListener != null) {
        mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }
}
```

//JAVA userInfo Object

```
public class UserInformation {

private String userName;
private String phoneNumber;
private String userEmail;


public UserInformation(){
}


public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

public String getPhoneNumber() {
    return phoneNumber;
}

public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}

public String getUserEmail() {
    return userEmail;
}

public void setUserEmail(String userEmail) {
    this.userEmail = userEmail;
}

public UserInformation(String userName, String phoneNumber, String userEmail) {
    this.userName = userName;
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    this.userEmail = userEmail;
}
```

}

So far what I tried, if I have just one child "Users", app reads and displays from database without any issues, once i add child "Restaurants" all goes bananas... I assume that I need somehow point the code to read child "Users" only as I am trying to display users info only, not the "Restaurants"?

//error message

```
2019-04-17 11:44:33.116 11557-11557/com.example.danie.dine E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.danie.dine, PID: 11557
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.danie.dine.Model.UserInformation.getUserName()' on a null object reference
    at com.example.danie.dine.Activities.HomeActivity.showInfo(HomeActivity.java:172)
    at com.example.danie.dine.Activities.HomeActivity.access$100(HomeActivity.java:30)
    at com.example.danie.dine.Activities.HomeActivity$2.onDataChange(HomeActivity.java:93)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:75)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:63)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:55)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

//proposed fix

```
mRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            UserInformation userDetails = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserInformation.class);
            userDetails.getUserName();
            userDetails.getPhoneNumber();
            userDetails.getUserEmail();
            userDetails.setUserName(dataSnapshot.child(userID).getValue(UserInformation.class).getUserName()); //get username
            userDetails.setUserEmail(dataSnapshot.child(userID).getValue(UserInformation.class).getUserEmail()); //get user email
            userDetails.setPhoneNumber(dataSnapshot.child(userID).getValue(UserInformation.class).getPhoneNumber()); //get user phone number
            lblUserName.setText(userDetails.getUserName());
            lblUserEmail.setText(userDetails.getUserEmail());
            lblUserPhone.setText(userDetails.getPhoneNumber());
```

Comment: Please add the entire code that you are using to get the data from the database/

Comment: Do you set your database reference before calling the query or listener? All i can see from your posted code is  mRef = mDatabase.getReference(); which if left like that will cause a problem.

Comment: Hi @Alex Mamo, apologise, missing part of code added. Thanks!

Comment: @DanielCzajka Shouldn't your `mRef` be defined as: `mDatabase.getReference().child("Users")`? Please responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: Hi Mena, I am guessing that this might be the source of my problem as well. I have just tried adding mRef=mDatabase.getReference().child("Users"); but still no play... @AlexMamo, just tried, same thing... it gives me java.lang.NullPointerException as it cannot read the info from db...

Comment: Please paste the entire error and indicate the exact line of code at which it occurs.

Comment: Hi @AlexMamo, I have added error message and comment next to the line of code error is pointing to. Thank you for looking after this!

Comment: Are you sure you are getting that error at that line? Because it `uInfo` cannot be `null` since it was just created earlier.

Comment: @DanielCzajka all `get` and `set` methods in **proposed fix** are not necessary as you're assigning an object with `dataSnapshot.getValue(UserInformation.class);`

Answer (score 0):

To keep it short

You have to create two methods: one `getUser()` and another `getRestaurant()` because the database as you presented it has two root nodes: Users and Restaurants.

If on the other hand you kept all users (meaning Users and Restaurants) on one list with an additional type attribute (`type:0` for User and `type:1` for Restaurant, or `type:user` and `type:restaurant`) a single database reference would be enough. All you'd have to do is to create BaseModel that UserModel and RestaurantModel should be extending and after reading `type` you'd create User or Restaurant.

I hope that answers your question.

Comment: Hi @Variag, thanks for your reply. For now I am trying to read the info from Users child only (showInfo() method). even if i do mRef = mDatabase.getReference().child("Users"); it still does not reading from "Users" child only and I don't know why...

Comment: @AlexMamo just double checked it, yup that is the line of code error is pointing. Basically none of these three (getUserName, getUserEmail, getUserPhone) seem to be working, I was commenting them one by one and always first not commented out was giving an error...

Comment: @DanielCzajka Is `dataSnapshot` before sending to `showInfo()` method not empty? Are values added to object `uInfo`? Are the values correct?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks alot for all your advices, I referred to firebase documentation and redo all read from database function from the scratch. It seem that my userInfo() method was not working, I got rid of it and created new (code added under //proposal fix comment. I hope that someone will find it useful. lesson learned :)